# ffmpeg dropping frames?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm running this command

```
C:\>ffmpeg -i file.flv -sameq file.mp4
```

It may take an hour, it says drop=27, and of course it's counting, increasing, that's after 4min.  Now 35 drops after 19500 frames.

Does this mean output will be significantly worse quality than input?

Should I add a switch?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

35 of 19500 is less than .18% ...  I would say don't worry about it(the human eye can only perceive so many frames per second after all).

Comment: hmm, 13sec in 2 hours .  say 12sec in 2h.  That could be visible. and could even effect the talking in the video. losing some  perhaps?  Is there a switch to stop it dropping frames?

Comment: the frames should be relatively evenly dispersed.  usually drops on occasion are okay.  if you must then try adjusting your fps and it might fix some things for you...

Comment: I said it -could- affect the talking.  I know if it's evenly dispersed and it probably is, then it might not affect the talking and probably won't perhaps noticeably affect it. But it could.  More fps might I suppose drop more and less fps might I suppose lose the name amount of talking but by dropping less frames.

Comment: acodec copy so it doesn't re-encode will make sure you have an exact copy of the audio. man ffmpeg

Comment: my ffmpeg install drops a similar number of frames for re-encoding video.  check the recent videos at http://vimeo.com/user2243209/videos .  The earlier ones I was still fiddling with the ffmpeg settings.  any artifacts are due to compiz during capture not frame rate or dropped frames.